# Does android encryption encrypt free space?

Tags: encryption

The situation is that I used wipe without encrypting first so that people can still recover data. If I now encrypt and then wipe, will the free space also get encrypted so that no one can recover anything?

Comment: What version of Android do you have?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Slashdot comments](http://it.slashdot.org/story/14/07/13/1239213/want-to-ensure-your-personal-android-data-is-truly-wiped-turn-on-encryption), the encryption is done on the entire partition (including free space), but if you are not confident in this, there are apps like [Secure Erase with iShredder 3](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.projectstar.ishredder.android.standard), which does a secure wipe on the free space.

Comment: [Lollipop doesn't encrypt free space](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/security/encryption/).  But yes, zeroing the free space is the best idea.